# AxisFault:SOAP request failed to match any part of the message

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I write a client according to the company's WSDL address。bue when i run this client it can't send success ! 
URL:http://172.18.173.201:8087/services/TJYYService?wsdl

Exception is:

```
AxisFault
faultCode:{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server
faultSubcode:
faultString:The xpath '//ns1:payload' configured to populate the message body from the incoming SOAP request failed to match any part of the message.
faultActor:htt[://172.18.173.201:8087/services/TJYYService
faultNode:
faultDetail:
   {http://www.orionhealth.com/rhapsody/2009/11/faultDetails}RhapsodyFaultDetails:<rfd:Code xmlns:rwsp="http://www.orionhealth.com/rhapsody/....>
```

this is my code :

```
  public class testTJYYService{ 
    try{
       String endpoint = "http://172.18.173.201:8087/services/TJYYService";
       Service service = new Service();
            Call call = (Call)service.createCall(); 
            call.setTargetEndpointAddress(new URL(endpoint));
            String xml = "45060319850405100635";
            call.setOperationName(new QName(endpoint,"sendXML"));
            String result = (String)call.invoke(new Object[]{xml});
          }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

this is my  parts of  wsdl :

```
targetNamespace="TJYYWebServiceApplication"
<wsdl:documentation>TJYY</wsdl:documentation>
+<wsdl:message name="sendXMLFault">
+<wsdl:message name="sendXMLRequest">
+<wsdl:message name="sendXMLResponse">
-<wsdl:portType name="TJYYServicePortType">
  -<wsdl:operation name="sendXML">
   <wsdl:documentation>sendXML</wsdl:documentation>
   <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="urn:sendXML" message="ns0:sendXMLRequest"></wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="TJYYWebServiceApplication/TJYYServicePortType/sendXMLFault" message="ns0:sendXMLFault"></wsdl:output >
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
-<wsdl:binding type="ns0:TJYYServicePortType" name="TJYYServiceSoap12Binding">
 <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
-<wsdl:operation name="sendXML">
  <soap12:operation style="document" soapAction="urn:sendXML"/>
-<wsdl:input>
   <soap12:body use="literal"/>
 </wsdl:input>
-<wsdl:output>
    <soap12:body use="literal"/>
 </wsdl:output>
-<wsdl:fault name="sendXMLFault">
   <soap12:fault name="sendXMLFault" use="literal"/>
</wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
```

please help me ! thank you!

Comment: I believe it is looking for your data to be the value of a payload element.  As in <payload>45060319850405100635</payload>

Comment: I don't understand. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Try 'String xml = "<payload>45060319850405100635</payload>";'  It may also require this to be complete XML with a namespace and the XML start tag.

Comment: But i use Myeclipse comes with Web Services Explore send is succeed.just code failed.

Comment: Use fiddler to capture both requests and compare.  The success call will show you exactly how the data should be formatted.